# Flutter AndroidX migration missing android.x packages

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, mobile, androidx

A while back I migrated my flutter project to androidx. All my plugins are using androidx packages. 
I am doing some work on the native side so I wanted to request permission to write a file to the device and when I try to import the 
androidx.core packages and other support libraries that contain ContextCompat. I get the error "androidx.core.packagefolder.packagename" cannot be found. If I try to refactor the project it says "No usage found"
Appreciate any help

Here is my build.gradle file

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.quiz"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.tom_roush:pdfbox-android:1.8.10.1'
//    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3'
//    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
}
```

I am using an external library in my main activity and i don't know if this may have affected anything here

Comment: Did you ```add android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true``` to gradle.properties file?

Comment: Yes I did. All my plugins are using androidx packages